# Why does @Table not work for me?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anybody tell why is this query not working?

```
DECLARE @unwantedRows TABLE 
( 
    ProductId INT, 
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    Description VARCHAR(50),
    Category VARCHAR(50),
    Repetitions VARCHAR(50)

);

Select *
INTO @unwantedRows From
(
Select a.*,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId)  As [Repetitons]  from tblProduct a
) As A

Where A.Repetitons > 1
```

Error i get is

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '@unwantedRows'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'.

**Edit :**

Now it's giving with `Repetitions` :-

```
INSERT
INTO @unwantedRows 
Select a.*,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId)  As [Repetitons]  from tblProduct a
Where a.Repetitons > 1
```

`

`Invalid column name 'Repetitons'.`

Comment: You spelled Repetitions wrong in the query but not in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error i found is its not **select into** its **select .. insert into** statement

Following query working fine without errors i.e syntax error

```
DECLARE @unwantedRows TABLE 
( 
    ProductId INT, 
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    Description VARCHAR(50),
    Category VARCHAR(50),
    Repetitions VARCHAR(50)

);

insert INTO @unwantedRows 
Select a.*,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId)  As [Repetitons]  from tblProduct 
Where A.Repetitons > 1
```

insetead of above query you can also try this

```
insert INTO @unwantedRows 
select * from (
Select a.*,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId)  As [Repetitons]  from tblProduct ) d
Where d.Repetitons > 1
```

Comment: Please read my edited post. Btw, `Where A.Repetitons > 1` should be `Where a.Repetitons > 1`

Comment: Nice. But this time there is surely a mistake. It should be `tblProduct a` instead of `tblProduct`. Thanks it works. Voted

Answer (score 1):

Because `select into` creates a table, and you want `insert into @unwantedRows select * from ...`

---

EDIT

And then, you're not allowed to use a window function (such as Partition) in a `Where` clause. If you must do it, wrap your select into another select:

```
select * from (select * from ...) as a where a.Partition > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the SELECT INTO and you need to specify your columns.

```
INSERT @unwantedRows 
SELECT a.ProductID, a.ProductName, a.Description, a.Category, a.Repetitions
FROM (
    Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId) As [Repetitons]  
    from tblProduct) As A
Where A.Repetitons > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into @unwantedRows 
Select * from
(
Select a.*,Row_Number() Over(Partition By ProductId Order By ProductId)  As [Repetitons]  from tblProduct a
) As A
Where A.Repetitons > 1
```

Comment: I think `from` keyword is missing in `Select`?

Comment: Yep thanx on tip, I edited my answer, Here on SO is so rush to answer first that I did not have time to duble check